# Printing out the standard input of another process?

Tags: pipe, ipc

### Problem Statement

Hi all, I am trying to learn about unix pipes and how they work. I want to do the following and was hoping I could get some help.

1. I will create a named pipe, `pipe0`,  using the FIFO command.
2. I want one process to listen for keyboard input and write that to pipe0.
3. I want another process to read from pipe0 and emit the characters as they come in.

In other words, I want two terminals open.
The first terminal has the process in bullet point 2 that I described, the second terminal has the process in bullet point 3.
When the user is focused on terminal 1 and starts typing into their keyboard, I want terminal 2 to show the characters they typed.

How can I do this?

### Attempted Solution 1

I have tried the following in Python.
For the process that will be reading keyboard input I had

```py
import sys
f = open("pipe0", "w")
sys.stdin = f
```

And for the process that is reading from pipe0 and emitting to standard out, I had

```py
import f = open("pipe0", "r")
sys.stdout = f
```

But this did not work.

### Attempted Solution 2

The following is closer to what I want but is not the exact behavior. Instead of process #2 printing characters one by one as I type them in process 1, process #2 only prints each newline at a time.

```py
# Reads user input and writes it to pipe0
import sys
f = open("pipe0", "w")
for line in sys.stdin:
  f.write(line)
  f.flush()
```

```py
# Reads pipe0 and writes it to stdout
f = open("pipe0", "r")
for line in f: 
  print(line)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like pseudo terminals are a good solution for what I am trying to do, but I was hoping to use a single-named pipe to do it.